# How to make different class for DB connections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource

I am developing a spring boot application and i need a common class to provide me Database Connections for all the controllers So I create a sepeate class As below:

```
@RestController
public class DataBaseConnector{


     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("dataSource")
     public static DataSource dataSource;

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds")
        public DataSource DataSourcePGStreet() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

       @Autowired
       public Connection giveConnection() throws SQLException{
           return dataSource.getConnection();
       }


}
```

Then In another Controller i call the connection as below:

```
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("dbc")
    private static DataBaseConnector obj;
@Autowired
 private Connection connectionDatabase;

.../// Rest Code
    @RequestMapping(value="/path",produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity<?> getStreetScore(){


     obj=new DataBaseConnector();
     connectionDatabase=obj.giveConnection();



}
```

But this throws me an error of

Error creating of name with DataBaseConnector.Any help is appreciated

Full Stack Trace[image: Stacktrace]

[image: Updated Stack trace]

Description:

```
Field dataSource in com.dmmltasmu.controller.DataBaseConnector required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace

Comment: @ChristofferPass added full stacktrace

Comment: Use this guide: https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Worked for me.

Comment: Don't do that. You cannot inject to `static` fields and if you want something just create a `JdbcTemplate` to work with JDBC. Don't try to inject a `Connection` like you do, well that is unless you want to run into an unresponsive db, connection leaks and weird to debug transaction issues.

Comment: So How to create connections from the DataBaseConnector connection pool seperately

Comment: Just don't. Why do you need a plain connection use the `JdbcTemplate`. Also why are you defining the datasource yourself? Spring Boot already provides one.

Comment: I want to create the connections and take control over it to monitor that's why ia m doing like this this.Can you help me why am i getting the second updated exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't autowire the static fields. Ugly but if you want to try below one

```
@Component
public class AnotherController {

private static DataBaseConnectionProvider obj;

@Autowired
public void setDataBaseConnectionProvider(DataBaseConnectionProvider obj) {
    AnotherController.obj = obj;
}}
```

Comment: I removed static but still get error.See updated error

Answer (score 2):

You use static

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("dataSource")
 public static DataSource dataSource;
```

Spring cannot autowire `static`. Remove the `static`

You can try to autowire by method and asign to thee static but this is awful approach.

The same in the

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dbc")
private static DataBaseConnector obj;
```

Remove static.

BTW java naming convention supposes method names start from lower case. Correct the

```
DataSourcePGStreet
```

Comment: I removed static but still get error.See updated error

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to inject a `Connection` that will lead to errors and hard to debug issues. Just use a `JdbcTemplate` to do JDBC access don't make your life harder.

Next to that `@Autowired` on `static` fields won't work you can only inject into non `static` fields.

Assuming you have configured your `spring.datasource` properties accordingly (if not rename your `spring.ds` properties to `spring.datasource`) that way Spring will automatically configure a `DataSource` and [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html).

Judging from your code just delete your `DataBaseConnector`.

And to use the `JdbcTemplate` just inject it.

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

@RequestMapping(value="/path",produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getStreetScore(){
    Obj result = jdbc.queryForObject(<your-query>, new RowMapper() { ... });
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```

Or whatever your implementation was.

Comment: But will this work as a connection pool.Because I may need lots of connections later on

Comment: That depends, your `DataSource` should be the connection pool, you shouldn't invent your own. If you datasource is a proper implementation then yes, if you expect something like `DriverManagerDataSource` from Spring to be a proper connection pool then no as that isn't implemented as one.

Comment: That's why i used the earlier method where I create a pool and get connections.But this one I am not getting it.if you don't mind can you expalin a bit more

Comment: You don't create a pool. You create a component that returns a single connection. The `DataSource` IS your connection pool.

Comment: How to make it as a pool then?

Comment: By selecting a proper implementation like [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) which is a proper implementation.

Comment: I am using Java 7 so i cannot use Row mapper it seems :(

Comment: Wy on earth wouldn't you be able to use it? That has been part of Spring since Spring 0.9 on java 1.2...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150081/discussion-between-ricky-and-m-deinum).